# In the Nav Menu Display categories if they have products

Tags: magento-1.8

I only want to display the categories in Navigation Menu which has product associated with it. Categories without products shouldn't be displayed. I have tried below code but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated

```
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();  
$_rootCatId     = 7;  
$_rootCategory  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_rootCatId);  
$collection = $_rootCategory->getChildrenCategories($_storeId);
```

I have checked $collection->ProdcutCount() > 0.
But its not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To display categories if you there is product assigned, you need to hide categories which don't have product items.

You can do it by rewriting some of the core files. One of my friend has wrote an article about you. You can read it from there. The link of the article is [Hide Categories without product](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/hide-categories-without-products-in-magento/)